# PropertyInfo.GetValue on Boolean is always True, how to handle False responses

Tags: c#, reflection

Similar to [PropertyInfo.GetValue on Boolean is always True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373564/propertyinfo-getvalue-on-boolean-is-always-true#) although no useful answer was posted.

I'm using Entity Framework to gather objects from a database and I'm trying to create Json structures as strings. However when gathering boolean answers in the same way as other types, the boolean always returns true.

I've tried to cast the value to a boolean here but I originally tried using the same method as other types (just using value). Is there a reason for this or a fix? Thanks

```
private static void AppendObjectPropertiesInJson(StringBuilder content, Object obj)
        {
            content.Append("    {\n");
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyInfo.PropertyType) ?? propertyInfo.PropertyType;

                var name = propertyInfo.Name;
                var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);

                if (value == null)
                    content.Append("        \"" + name + "\": null,\n");
                // Error, always returns true
                else if (type == typeof(bool))
                {
                    value = (bool)value;
                    content.Append("        \"" + name + "\": " + value.ToString().ToLower() + ",\n");
                }
                else if (type == typeof(int))
                    content.Append("        \"" + name + "\": " + value.ToString().ToLower() + ",\n");
                else if (type == typeof(string))
                    content.Append("        \"" + name + "\": " + "\"" + value.ToString() + "\",\n");
                // TODO: Handle arrays
            }
            content.Append("    },\n");
        }
```

**edit**: Issue was with unexpected changes in database. Thanks to everybody who helped show there was no issue with this code

Comment: post your object and how you call this function and also post your result. because it seems reflection should work for boolean as well as for other types

Comment: Your code doesnt appear to have any problems with false bools: https://dotnetfiddle.net/m9ntlM

Comment: I do wonder why you're hand crafting JSON also, when JSON serializers (of many types) exist

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad this has been the same result for multiple objects. All created in Entity Framework from my database

Comment: @Jamiec this may be the easiest way to fix, although it would be nice to see why this wasn't working for me

Comment: @JoeArnold Unless you can provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem Im not sure we can tell you - as you can see in my dotnetfiddle link it appears to work just fine

Comment: using json serializer is not easiest way but that is the best way because that is error safe! and as @Jamiec said your current code is working maybe the problem is some where else.

Comment: @Jamiec will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The premise of the question is incorrect; `PropertyInfo.GetValue` works just fine - here used with your method with zero changes:

```cs
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new Foo { Bar = true, Blap = false };
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        AppendObjectPropertiesInJson(sb, obj);
        Console.WriteLine(sb);
    }

    class Foo
    {
        public bool Bar { get; set; }
        public bool Blap { get; set; }
    }
```

outputs the almost-JSON:

```
    {
        "Bar": true,
        "Blap": false,
    },
```

Note that the expression `value = (bool)value` is a redundant unbox+box, but: it doesn't change any results (just: it doesn't do anything useful, either).

Note that we can show native `bool` here too:

```cs
else if (type == typeof(bool))
{
    var typed = (bool)value;
    Console.WriteLine(typed ? "it was true" : "it was false");
    // ...content.Append("        \"" + name + "\": " + value.ToString().ToLower() + ",\n");
}
```

If you have an example where `PropertyInfo.GetValue` doesn't work, then *post that example*. Additionally, note that writing your own JSON output is not recommended, as is very easy to get wrong.

Comment: Something else in the line is causing the error. Thanks for your help everybody